# Merge and delete rows according to two columns value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with times and locations and I want to merge rows with the same date and location so the maximum time will move to "to" column and the row that I just used its time value will be removed.

also, If the time difference is longer then 3 hours so the merge won't happen.

```
date    from    location    to
    01  16:25       A   
    02  17:15       B   
    02  19:11       C   
    02  19:19       C
    02  17:48       B   
    03  16:20       F   
    05  08:30       G   
    05  09:09       D   
    05  09:11       G
```

expected output:

```
date    from    location    to
    01  16:25       A       16:25
    02  17:15       B       17:48   
    02  19:11       C       19:19
    02  19:19       C      #this line will delete
    02  17:48       B      #this line will delete
    03  16:20       F       16:20   
    05  08:30       G       08:30   
    05  09:09       D       09:09
    05  09:11       G       09:11
```

I tried it with a double for loop but I'm sure there is a better pythonic way.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why the `to` values at the 1st `G` location row is `8:30` ?

Comment: Because the next location is different

Comment: So why the 2nd `B` location row is deleted ?

Comment: Your output does not make sense. First of all the question of @AlexandreB. second. Why is row 1 of `C` not `19:19`? That's the max time of that group

Comment: The 2nd B is the next time stamp on this day so I could merge them together. The C row is my mistake..fixed

Comment: _"the 2nd `B` is the next time stamp on this day"_  following this logic, why do you make a difference between the two `G` rows? They are also the same day

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02"],
        "time": ["01:02", "02:03", "04:05", "06:07", "08:09", "12:10"],
        "location": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    }
)

# convert time column to datetime
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%H:%M")

# aggregate by date and location
df = df.groupby(["date", "location"]).agg(["min", "max"]).reset_index()

# rename columns
df.columns = ["date", "location", "to", "from"]

# sort out where diff > 3
df = df[(df['to'] - df['from']).astype('timedelta64[h]').abs() <= 3]

# convert to and from to datetime.time
df['to'] = df['to'].dt.time
df['from'] = df['from'].dt.time
```

```
date location        to      from
0   01        A  01:02:00  02:03:00
1   01        B  04:05:00  06:07:00
```

Comment: The solution doesn't take into account the "3hours constraint"

Comment: You can filter out that difference after merging if you like. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Updated it. Must have missed your note about the 3 hour limit before.